# Creating a new column in my data frame based on a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a data frame that has NFL teams and some data about them. I'm wanting to add Points per game for each team for that particular week.
I cannot just summarize the data by team as I need the individual game the way it's currently represented.

```
    CurrYrfun <- function(Yr,Tm,Wk){
  PPG <- Schedule_Results %>% 
    filter(Year == Yr & Team == Tm & Week < Wk) %>% 
    group_by(Team) %>% 
    summarize(APG = mean(Pts))
  return(PPG[['APG']])
}
```

This function gives the correct result for individual records, but when I try to mutate a new column in the dataframe as below:

```
    Schedule_Results <- Schedule_Results %>% 
  mutate(PPG = CurrYrfun(Year, Team, Week))
```

I get an error saying PPG is of length 0. I've tried to attach a picture of the dataframe, so you have an idea of the data I'm working with.[dataframe snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84rq6.png)

Edited to include data and examples:

```
Schedule_Results <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Week = c(17, 17, 17, 
 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 
 11, 11), Team = c("Washington Redskins", "Cincinnati Bengals", 
 "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Washington Redskins", 
 "Cincinnati Bengals", "Cincinnati Bengals", "Washington Redskins", 
 "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Washington Redskins", "Cincinnati Bengals", 
 "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Washington Redskins", 
 "Cincinnati Bengals", "Cincinnati Bengals", "Jacksonville Jaguars", 
 "Washington Redskins", "Washington Redskins", "Jacksonville Jaguars", 
 "Cincinnati Bengals"), Opp = c("Dallas Cowboys", "Cleveland Browns", 
 "Indianapolis Colts", "Atlanta Falcons", "New York Giants", "Miami Dolphins", 
 "New England Patriots", "Philadelphia Eagles", "Oakland Raiders", 
 "Green Bay Packers", "Cleveland Browns", "Los Angeles Chargers", 
 "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Carolina Panthers", "New York Jets", 
 "Pittsburgh Steelers", "Tennessee Titans", "Detroit Lions", "New York Jets", 
 "Indianapolis Colts", "Oakland Raiders"), Pts = c(16, 33, 38, 
 12, 35, 35, 13, 27, 20, 15, 19, 10, 11, 29, 22, 10, 20, 19, 17, 
 13, 10), Opp_Pts = c(47, 23, 20, 24, 41, 38, 34, 37, 16, 20, 
 27, 45, 28, 21, 6, 16, 42, 16, 34, 33, 17), Yds = c(271, 361, 
 353, 288, 361, 430, 315, 352, 262, 262, 451, 252, 242, 362, 277, 
 244, 369, 230, 225, 308, 246), Opp_Yds = c(517, 313, 275, 518, 
 552, 502, 291, 415, 364, 341, 333, 525, 315, 278, 271, 338, 471, 
 364, 400, 389, 386), TO = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), Opp_TO = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2), Home = c("1", "1", 
 "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
 "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1"), Playoffs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), win = c("0", "1", 
 "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
 "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
CurrYrfun <- function(Yr,Tm,Wk){
  PPG <- Schedule_Results %>% 
    filter(Year == Yr & Team == Tm & Week < Wk) %>% 
    group_by(Team) %>% 
    summarize(APG = mean(Pts))
  return(PPG[['APG']])
}

CurrYrfun(2019,'Washington Redskins',13)
CurrYrfun(2019,'Jacksonville Jaguars',14)
CurrYrfun(2019,'Washington Redskins',16)
CurrYrfun(2019,'Cincinnati Bengals',15)

Schedule_Results <- Schedule_Results %>% 
  mutate(PPG = CurrYrfun(Year, Team, Week))
```

My goal is to return the output of the function for each row as a new column in the dataframe

Comment: can't you just use mutate instead of sumarize?

Comment: We can probably help you debug if you share sample input and desired output. Please use `dput()` to share sample input, something like `dput(Schedule_Results[1:10, ])`--or some other suitable subset if the first 10 rows aren't a good choice. It's very hard to work with pictures of data....

Comment: you should learn how functions work in `dplyr`: try reading the whole of [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, I believe my issue is that when my function is added to the second chunk of code, it is not taking my column names as input as desired. How can I fix that?

Comment: @GregorThomas I have updated my question to include those items. Sorry for not being clear initially, it's my first time posting

Comment: Thanks for the sample data, that helps a lot! Can you describe in words what your code is doing? It looks like, for each team and year, you are taking a cumulative mean of `Pts` by week---all weeks before the current week? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you want. I spot-checked the first couple examples you give, and they look right.

```
 Schedule_Results %>%
   group_by(Team, Year) %>%
   arrange(Week) %>%
   mutate(PPG = lag(cummean(Pts), 1))
# # A tibble: 21 x 14
# # Groups:   Team, Year [3]
#     Year  Week Team             Opp                Pts Opp_Pts   Yds Opp_Yds    TO Opp_TO Home  Playoffs win     PPG
#    <int> <dbl> <chr>            <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1  2019    11 Washington Reds~ New York Jets       17      34   225     400     1      2 0            0 0      NA  
#  2  2019    11 Jacksonville Ja~ Indianapolis Co~    13      33   308     389     1      2 1            0 0      NA  
#  3  2019    11 Cincinnati Beng~ Oakland Raiders     10      17   246     386     2      2 1            0 0      NA  
#  4  2019    12 Cincinnati Beng~ Pittsburgh Stee~    10      16   244     338     2      1 0            0 0      10  
#  5  2019    12 Jacksonville Ja~ Tennessee Titans    20      42   369     471     1      2 1            0 0      13  
#  6  2019    12 Washington Reds~ Detroit Lions       19      16   230     364     2      4 1            0 1      17  
#  7  2019    13 Jacksonville Ja~ Tampa Bay Bucca~    11      28   242     315     4      1 0            0 0      16.5
#  8  2019    13 Washington Reds~ Carolina Panthe~    29      21   362     278     0      2 0            0 1      18  
#  9  2019    13 Cincinnati Beng~ New York Jets       22       6   277     271     0      0 1            0 1      10  
# 10  2019    14 Washington Reds~ Green Bay Packe~    15      20   262     341     1      1 1            0 0      21.7
...
```

Comment: The data.table version would be `setDT(Schedule_Results)[order(Week), PPG := shift(cummean(Pts)), .(Team, Year)]`